# SVG img preserveAspectRatio Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg

when I use preserveAspectRatio=none for an image in a  SVG file it does not seem to work in Google Chrome. 
The SVG does not scale according to the image width and height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg  id="test" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
viewBox="0 0 1024 768"> 
<defs>
</defs>
<image x="288" y="140" width="368" height="160" xlink:href="image.svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" />
</svg>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg  id="test" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
viewBox="0 0 1024 768"> 
<defs>
</defs>
<image x="288" y="140" width="368" height="160" xlink:href="image.svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" />
</svg>
```

In IE9, latest Opera and FF it works!

It seems that it does not work if the image that should be included has not the attribute preserveAspectRatio=none.
I cannot assume that every SVG has this attribute. So I need to know how to overwrite such an attribute in case the SVG is embedded with 'image' tag.

Comment: `none` works now (Chrome 60, July 2017), but the other values are interpreted as `xMinYMid meet`.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute
Please try "defer".
But I think chrome does not support this value.

Comment: I tried:    <image x="288" y="140" width="368" height="160" xlink:href="image.svg" preserveAspectRatio="defer none" />
did not work