# Raphael and preserveAspectRatio

Tags: svg, raphael

With RaphaelJS, this command inserts an image:-

`var myImg = paper.image('image.svg', 100, 100, 150,150);`

and the SVG output is:-

`<image x="100" y="100" width="150" height="150" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="image.svg"/>`

Question: How do I directly access `preserveAspectRatio` attribute and change it to `xMidYMid meet` - if you examine `myImg.attr()`, it doesnt show this attribute.

The roundabout way is navigate the SVG DOM tree, and execute `svgImg.setAttributeNS(null,"preserveAspectRatio" , "xMidYMid meet" );`

Note: Only some images require `none` while the rest needs the `xMidYMid meet` tag. Hence I can't set this attribute on parent <svg>

Note2: Chrome doesn't support [preserveAspectRatio with SVG images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626588/svg-img-preserveaspectratio-chrome). Use FF or IE to test.

Comment: Looks like the bug in Chrome with pAR=none in SVG images was fixed about a year ago, it should work in Chrome 28 and later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the source code level, `preserveAspectRatio` is hardcoded to `none`

**Answer** The quickest way to change this:-;

> myImg[0].preserveAspectRatio.baseVal.align = 6     (1 = off, 6 = xMidYMid)
>   myImg[0].preserveAspectRatio.baseVal.meetOrSlice = 1     (1 = meet, 2 = slice)

Update:- jQuery style:-

> jQuery(myImg.node).prop('preserveAspectRatio').baseVal.align = 6 ;
>   jQuery(myImg.node).prop('preserveAspectRatio').baseVal.meetOrSlice = 1 ;

Raphael's docs for `Element.node` *"Gives you a reference to the DOM object, so you can assign event handlers or just mess around. Note: Don’t mess with it."*

Comment: I'm pretty sure jQuery wont work in setting `preserveAspectRatio` because jQuery decapitalizes attribute names before inserting them into the DOM, and SVG, being strict XML, is case sensitive. he will need to use the native DOM methods directly

Comment: You're correct, updating the jQuery answer. The other alternative is to edit (in 4 places) raphael.js to accept preserveAspectRatio.

Answer (score 0):

You can call these parameters on the Raphael canvas as a whole.

First create SVG:
var paper = Raphael('content',xSize,ySize);

Place image in it:
paper.image('image.svg', 100, 100, 150,150);

Then change attributes of svg:
paper.canvas.setAttribute('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid meet');